# Why is my javascript call to an object method not working?

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects

I am trying to learn object oriented javascript. Why is this call to an object method not working (no alert)?

http://jsfiddle.net/hxPqJ/2/

When you click on the link, an alert is supposed to appear stating how old Bob is.

In case the link ever disappears, here is the HTML:

```
<a href="#" onclick="bob.say()">eh</a>​
```

and here is my javascript.

```
function guy(person_name) {
  this.name = person_name;
  this.age = 32;
  this.say = function() {
    alert(this.name + " is " + this.age);
    return false;
  }
}

  var bob = new guy("Bob");
```

​
Chrome Web Developer Console states

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: bob is not defined
```

However, I think I defined `bob` with `var bob = new guy("Bob");`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are missing the closing `}` on `say()`.

Beyond that, you must not return a value from the object constructor function. Doing so will simply set the variable `bob` to `false`.

```
function Guy(person_name) {
  this.name = person_name;
  this.age = 32;
  this.say = function() {
    alert(this.name + " is " + this.age);};
}

var bob = new Guy("Bob");
```

Note also that JavaScript conventions typically dicatate that an object constructor be capitalized like `function Guy()`

[Here is the updated fiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/hxPqJ/9/)

Comment: Thank you, not returning in the constructor makes sense. Without returning false though, how do I prevent the click event from bubbling up the DOM tree?

Comment: @DavidFaux: Put `return false;` in the inline handler.

Comment: @Michae​l: David's Javascript is actually fully valid, but mis-indented.  See my answer.

Comment: @SLaks No, the original fiddle posted before the code was posted here was missing the `}` http://jsfiddle.net/hxPqJ/

Answer (score 6):

You need to select one of the `no wrap` options in jsFiddle's left pane.

Otherwise, jsFiddle wraps your code in an event handler, and poor `bob` is stuck as a local variable.

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/hxPqJ/10/)

Answer (score 0):

When I ran you code a message of

```
bob is not defined
```

showed up on the console. I think this is a JSFiddle quirk, since things worked when I changed things to set the onclick on the Javascript side instead of in the HTML.

```
<a href="#" id="foo">eh</a>

document.getElementById("foo").onclick = function(){ bob.say(); }
```

http://jsfiddle.net/hxPqJ/6/